# WPF Datagrid: updated too often - selection gets lost

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a Datagrid with a data Binding to the data. I implemented the interface INotifyPropertyChanged and it works pretty good.

One Thing I noticed was, when the user now selects a row in the datagrid and the data is updated, the selection is lost. Since the update occurs frequently, the user can't really select/change something.

My first approach is to reduce the updates to a minimum - still that's at least one update per second. So every second the selection is lost.

Is there a way to keep the user selection despite of the updates? How do you guys deal with that?

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Plz post some sample code. You might also want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825368/how-to-keep-my-selection-to-the-datagrid-row-after-refresh-the-data-grid-using-t/17826621#17826621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to deal with this is to create a private field of the same type as the items in your `DataGrid` and simply set this field to the value of the `SelectedRow` just *before* you update and then set the `DataGrid.SelectedRow` property back to the field value just *after* the update. To the use, it will *appear* as though the selected row remains selected... unless your updates take a long time, in which case, you should do them on a background thread.